# Increasing loudness while using VLC-Player to copy videos

Tags: video, audio, processing, vlc-media-player

I film via a videocamera with has a microphone that unfortunatly often not loud enough.
That camera stores the videos on mini DVD and at the moment I copy the videos from the camera to my computer via a batch file.
Is there a command in VLC-Player that allows me to double the volume of the file that gets created?

Comment: i don't have a good VLC-specific answer.  for your purposes i'd seriously recommend using a real video editing toolchain and processing your audio separately.  vlc is a great player, and workable as a transcoder, but for real quality results you shouldn't be transcoding before the video even gets to the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC can while transcoding convert the audio codec and/or change the bitrate, but it doesn't have an option for changing the loudness. You need for that a more specialized product.

Although you haven't specified your operating system, I'll assume that it's Windows.
In that case, Windows Movie Maker can do that.

From [Adjusting audio in Windows Movie Maker: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Adjusting-audio-in-Windows-Movie-Maker-frequently-asked-questions):

> **How can I adjust the audio levels of music and audio that are playing at
>   the same time so that I can hear
>   both?**
>
> The default audio setting in Windows
>   Movie Maker is for the audio portion
>   of imported video and any narration or
>   music that you add to play at equal
>   levels, but you can change that
>   setting if it does not give you the
>   balance that you want. To adjust the
>   audio levels, do the following:
>
> 1. Click Tools, and then click Audio Levels.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>      a. To increase the level of audio on the
>      Audio track that is part of a video
>      clip, drag the slider toward Audio
>      from video.
>      b. To increase the
>      level of audio that is on the
>      Audio/Music track, drag the slider
>      toward Audio/Music.
> 3. Click Close.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is normalize the audio - some details in [this article](http://www.thefreewindows.com/?p=2499)

Comment: yet that article compresses the audio, which means it would actually lose some of the sound dynamics.

Answer (score -1):

[Vlc │ { Cnvrt∕Sv(Ctrl+R) _ (Prfl){T-1} _ [ Encaps-Mp4∕Mov│Video-Ori│Audi(Increase)↑En-Codec_Mp3∕Filters!Equal(10ᵴ) . . ] } │ ( FlNm ) . . ( Vɨdꬳꝋ-Ꝋrɨ ; ) Audi↑Increase!(_B∕€ncꝋdꬳ-Pꬰrꬰ_Hɨ-Lvl∕Gd) (.Mp4) .Png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onNRE.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).